# new Date() not working when phpToPDF is called, must it render in browser?

Tags: javascript, date, pdf-generation

```
var d=new Date(value);
```

value is simply the date in a mySQL data pull ie. 2016-01-01
When we run a php page that has some javascript on it to convert that date to a more usable output it works just fine. When we run the same page using the phpToPDF engine the whole page saves correctly but when opened the formatted dates appear as (undefined, undefined NaNth NaN ). It seems as though the page can't run new Date() unless the page is actually rendered and not saved in another format. All other javascript on the saved pages work but the date. 
Any thoughts?

```
$pdf_options = array(
  "source_type" => 'url',
  "source" => 'http://url/admin/approval/xxx.php?id='.$_GET["id"],
  "action" => 'save',
  "save_directory" => '/ip/xxx/xxx/outputFiles/',
  "file_name" => $_GET["id"].'xxx.pdf'
);
```

Comment: Just a comment, not a solution here: you did not give any examples of javascript that does work, but the Date would be calling the system for its current value, something that must be retrieved from outside of the application itself, and it sounds as if there's no mechanism to do so. (I suspect that a time call would fail as well.) Can you set the date value prior to passing the page to phpToPDF?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We tried everywhere calling Date and it wouldnt render. What we ended up doing is just calling the the Date using php and not javascript and it rendered just fine. I still have no idea why it wouldn't do so.